# Finding a user's most recent tweet

Tags: json, twitter

I want to know is there a way to do something like this to get a user's most recent tweet? So, the user would put in their twitter name and this could get their most recent post.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more detailed than this. What language are you using? What library? Have you tried writing any code already? Have you searched google for the answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this (PHP):

```
$username="user"; // set user name
$format="json"; // set format
$tweet=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/$username.$format")); // get tweets and decode them into a variable

echo $tweet[0]->text; // show latest tweet
```

For more information, take a look at [this](http://webhole.net/2010/03/16/get-last-tweet-with-php-or-jquery/).

JQuery Example:

```
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=?", function(data) {
     $("#twitter").html(data[0].text);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this without PHP?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it working. Thanks so much! I realize this was a very vague question, but your response was perfect, thanks!

Comment: How would I use jQuery to get the tweet back? I sent JSON data to this PHP script, how would I get that one tweet back to the page I sent the JSON data from?

Comment: I still don't understand how I get that last text back

Comment: Hey, just got back. In all honesty, I'm not sure either because I don't use the twitter API. I just googled how to get the first tweet.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show).